# Gain reputation for Windows SmartScreen by submitting exe file for malware analysis

Tags: windows, code-signing, app-distribution, smartscreen

I need to certificate a Window app which is distributed as exe installer outside the Microsoft App Store. I read that if you submit the app to Microsoft for malware analysis, the smartscreen will go away as soon as possible.
My question: is this process valid even if the app is not signed? I know that SmartScreen reputation gain is not well known and I don't want to buy an EV cert. Disabling SmartScreen is not a solution because it works only on local machine.

I tried to submit app for analysis, but SmartScreen is still there. Are there some difference between selecting security product used to scan file?